# Can't start Payara domain

Tags: payara

I've just installed the Payara zip file on Windows 10 and done everything README instructions have said. When I run

C:\Program Files\payara5\bin>asadmin start-domain

I get:

```
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1. Before it died, it produced the following output:

Launching Payara Server on Felix platform ERROR: Error parsing system bundle statement. ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/osgi-resource-locator.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]) ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm-analysis.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]) ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm.commons [20] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm-commons.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]) ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm.tree [21] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm-tree.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]) ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm.util [22] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm-util.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]) ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm [23] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]) ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/class-model.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.1.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.1.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]) ERROR: Bundle fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/config-types.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R
46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.inject)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]] Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]) ERROR: Bundle fish.payara.server.internal.core.glassfish [113] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.core.glassfish [113](R 113.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.core.glassfish [113](R
113.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.core.glassfish [113](R 113.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]) ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.api [131] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/hk2-api.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137](R 137.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137](R 137.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.inject)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]) ERROR: Bundle fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config [132] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/hk2-config.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config [132](R 132.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config [132](R 132.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management) Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config [132](R 132.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management)]) ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.locator [135] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/hk2-locator.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.locator [135](R 135.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.locator [135](R 135.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.api.messaging)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.inject)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.locator [135](R 135.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.api.messaging)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]) ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel [136] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/hk2-runlevel.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel [136](R 136.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel [136](R 136.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel [136](R 136.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]) ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/hk2-utils.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137](R 137.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137](R 137.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137](R 137.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)]) ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/jakarta.inject.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]) ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [305] Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/modules/osgi-adapter.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [305](R 305.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [305](R 305.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [305](R
305.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:865)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:217)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerRevision.update(ExtensionManager.java:982)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerRevision.access$000(ExtensionManager.java:885)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.updateRevision(ExtensionManager.java:378)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:748)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:93) WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlers (file:/C:/Program%20Files/payara5/glassfish/osgi/felix/bin/felix.jar) to constructor sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler() WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlers WARNING: Use
--illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release Dec 03, 2020 2:16:08 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner. org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.1.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.1.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R
46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [131](R 131.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.inject)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.locator [135](R 135.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.api.messaging)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel [136](R 136.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel [136](R 136.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel [136](R 136.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137](R 137.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137](R 137.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.utils [137](R 137.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.namespace)]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [160](R 160.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [305](R 305.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [305](R 305.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [305](R
305.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54) Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: No GlassFishRuntime available
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:124)
        ... 6 more Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: No GlassFishRuntime available
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.getGlassFishRuntime(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:208)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:168)
        ... 9 more Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.shutdown()" because the return value of "com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.access$000(com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher)" is null java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.shutdown()" because the return value of "com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.access$000(com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher)" is null
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:212)

Command start-domain failed.
```

I have tried to google this error and people suggest that Java version might be incompatible. But the README file says that my Java is supported.

```
C:\Program Files\payara5\bin>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)
```

Anyone knows what could be wrong?

Comment: What's the version of Payara Server?

Comment: README says Payara Server 5.2020.5 but I've tried latest Payara Server 5.2020.6 too